# Able to send email via SMTP from localhost, but not in production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

What could be possible reasons why my app cannot send emails once it's moved to the production environment?

I'm using my private e-mail address to send these emails and I learned via admin that the server is not blocking this. What would be other issues to look for?

Comment: Can you ping the mail server from your production server?

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean by 'learned via admin'? What admin?

Comment: I just tried pinging it, but was not able to do that. I'm pinging overall domain where my app folder is located and this times out. I cannot ping the app location in this folder. "learned via admin" I just meant I contacted the admin that mentioned that server does not block sending email via external smtp

Comment: If you can't ping the mail server, can you connect to it via code (ping may be disabled). If you can't do either then it sounds like some restriction your hosting provider has put on outgoing connections (port not allowed for instance), or maybe your mail server provider has blacklisted your hosting IP!

Comment: I would not know how to connect to it via code? The issue got sort of sorted, as I've set up the email account within this domain instead. Thanks for help anyways.

Comment: I meant just write a short app that connects but doesn't try to send a mail, then you can examine any error output. Glad you got got it working - sometimes thinking outside the box isn't good enough ... you may need a new box altogether!